# Node.js Eventloop неожиданное поведение

Tags: javascript, node.js, многопоточность, event-loop

```
const https = require('https');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
const start = Date.now();

function doRequest() {
    https.request('https://google.com', res => {
        res.on('data', () => { })
        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log('RQ:', Date.now() - start)
        })
    }).end()
}

function doHash(a) {
    crypto.pbkdf2('a', 'b', 100000, 512, 'sha512', () => {
        console.log('Hash:', a, ' ', Date.now() - start)
    })
}

doRequest()

fs.readFile('async.js', 'utf8', () => {
    console.log('FS:', Date.now() - start)
})
fs.readFile('async.js', 'utf8', () => {
    console.log('FS:', Date.now() - start)
})
fs.readFile('async.js', 'utf8', () => {
    console.log('FS:', Date.now() - start)
})
fs.readFile('async.js', 'utf8', () => {
    console.log('FS:', Date.now() - start)
})


doHash(1)
doHash(2)
doHash(3)
doHash(4)
```

Если запустить код в консоли то вывод следующий

```
RQ: 145
Hash: 1   1184
FS: 1185
FS: 1186
FS: 1186
FS: 1186
Hash: 3   1194
Hash: 2   1194
Hash: 4   1207
```

Node по умолчанию использует 4 потока, в них попадает 4 задачи на чтение файла, когда один из потоков освобождается так как требуется ждать ответа от жесткого диска он выполняет следующую задачу это как раз одна из функций doHash() она иполняется, затем приходят ответы от жесткого исполняются все fs.readFile, а затем оставшиеся в очереди doHash()

но если в конце кода убрать doHash(4) то вывод следующий

```
FS: 64
FS: 70
FS: 70
FS: 70
RQ: 164
Hash: 1   925
Hash: 2   934
Hash: 3   956
```

то есть в данном случае почему-то при простаивание не берется из очереди функция doHash() а исполняются сперва все fsReadFile()?

Comment: Вообще, насколько я понимаю, порядок выполнения асинхронных функция не гарантируется, они будут выполняться по мере готовности. Так что ваш пример зависит от целой кучи факторов. Если, например, файлы будут достаточно большие, то все `FS:` могут быть вызваны самыми последними.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, причина подобного поведения в том, что вы пишите асинхронный код, нода просто запускает их в фоне и не ждет окончания выполнения функции, запуская код далее.

Если вы хотите, чтобы все выполнялось синхронно - измените код на следующий

```
function doRequest() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        https.request('https://google.com', res => {
            res.on('data', () => { })
            res.on('end', () => {
                console.log('RQ:', Date.now() - start)
                resolve()
            })
            res.on('error', (e)=>{
                reject(e)
            })
        }).end()
    })
}

function doHash(a) {
    crypto.pbkdf2Sync('a', 'b', 100000, 512, 'sha512', () => {
        console.log('Hash:', a, ' ', Date.now() - start)
    })
}

doRequest().then(()=>{
    fs.readFileSync('async.js', 'utf8', () => {
        console.log('FS:', Date.now() - start)
    })
    fs.readFileSync('async.js', 'utf8', () => {
        console.log('FS:', Date.now() - start)
    })
    fs.readFileSync('async.js', 'utf8', () => {
        console.log('FS:', Date.now() - start)
    })
    fs.readFileSync('async.js', 'utf8', () => {
        console.log('FS:', Date.now() - start)
    })

    doHash(1)
    doHash(2)
    doHash(3)
    doHash(4)
}).catch(err=>{
    throw err;
})
```